# Display and calculate the sum of values in array - C language

Tags: arrays, c, filter

I'm practicing my homework, but I was stuck. After I made input to display this table. I need to filter choices. Please take a look my code below, it's unfinished, but I don't know how to display values based on their priority. For example, when I choose to display the summary cost of items having priority = 1, it should be `76600.90`; but my code shows the value of the first item only. And the sum was also displayed wrong number; it shows the summary of 5 items. Please help to explain the issue. Thank you very much.

```
Item |Priority |Financed |  Cost   |

--1--|---1-----|---n-----| 59900.15|

--2--|---3-----|---y-----| 100000.00|

--3--|---2-----|---n-----| 45700.25 |

--4--|---1-----|---y-----| 16700.75 |

--5--|---3-----|---n-----|7800.55   |

 -------------------------$230101.70
```

Code:

```
do {
    printf("\nHow do you want to forecast your wish list?\n"
           " 1. All items (no filter)\n"
           " 2. By priority\n"
           " 0. Quit/Exit\n");
    printf("Selection: ");
    scanf(" %d", &selection);
    if (selection == 1) {
        printf("\n====================================================\n");
        printf("Filter:   All items\n");
        printf("Amount:   $%10.2lf\n", sum);
        printf("Forecast: %d years, %d months\n",
                ((int)(sum / netIncome) / 12),
                (((int)(sum / netIncome) % 12) + 1));
        printf("====================================================\n");
    } else
    if (selection == 2) {   
        sum == 0;
        printf("\nWhat priority do you want to filter by? [1-3]: ");
        scanf(" %d", &priority[i]);           
        printf("\n====================================================\n");
        printf("Filter:   by priority (%d)\n", priority[i]);
        if (priority[i] == 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < item && priority[i] == 1; i++) {
                printf("%3d  %5d    %5c    %11.2lf\n",
                       i + 1, priority[i], finance[i], cost[i]);
                sum += cost[i];
            }
            printf("Amount:   $%10.2lf\n", sum);
            printf("Forecast: %d years, %d months\n",
                   ((int)(sum / netIncome) / 12),
                   (((int)(sum / netIncome) % 12) + 1));
            printf("====================================================\n");
        }
    } else
    if (selection < 0 || selection > 2) {
        printf("\nERROR: Invalid menu selection.\n");
    }
} while (selection != 0);
```

Comment: It is not productive for people to attempt to debug incomplete code snippets. For example, we don't really know how the data is stored. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: `sum == 0` does nothing. You won't get the right sum so VTC as a typo.

Comment: The summation loop control is incorrect too with `for (i = 0; i < item && priority[i] == 1; i++)`. Instead of ignoring a different priority, it terminates the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions of your `for` loop are `i < item && priority[i] == 1`. Your loop will terminate as soon it sees any item whose priority is not `1`.

Even though you only want to print out the items whose `priority == 1`, you still want to iterate over all the items in the array. So your code should look more like this:

```
sum = 0;
printf("\nWhat priority do you want to filter by? [1-3]: ");
scanf(" %d", &priority[i]);           
printf("\n====================================================\n");
printf("Filter:   by priority (%d)\n", priority[i]);
if (priority[i] == 1)
{
    for (i = 0; i < item; i++)
    {
        if (priority[i] == 1)
        {
            printf("%3d  %5d    %5c    %11.2lf\n", i + 1, priority[i], finance[i], cost[i]);
            sum += cost[i];
        }

    }
    printf("Amount:   $%10.2lf\n", sum);
    printf("Forecast: %d years, %d months\n", ((int)(sum / netIncome) / 12), (((int)(sum / netIncome) % 12) + 1));
              
    printf("====================================================\n");
}
```

(And, as commenters have pointed out, you should also make sure that you reset `sum` with `sum = 0` instead of `sum == 0`.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your suggest. I tried to post the whole cost and image of my homework, but there were some errors preventing me doing that. I dont know how to fix that error tho.